# I am trying to filter data to get rid of outliers (ideally 99% Conf. Interval) for various variables but get error with length

Tags: r

I am trying to filter data so it doesn't include tails with 99% confidence range to get rid of outliers for various variables but get error with length. I want it to be of length 127,789 though instead of approx. 130,000. I did a tedious code instead of a function but the ranges do work. I did the same for around 9 more variables but condensed it so it's not excessive in the body and can focus on just one variable. If you don't know how to solve it, also open to something more effective/efficient

```
ave <- mean(cf)
m.cf <- sapply(cf, ave)
s.cf <- sapply(cf, sd)
n.cf <- length(cf) - 1

error.cf <- qnorm(0.99)*s.cf/sqrt(n.cf)
left.cf <- m.cf-error.cf
right.cf <- m.cf+error.cf

new_data <- data1 %>% 
  filter(cf < right.cf) %>% 
  filter(cf > left.cf)

Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 130384 or 1, not size 127789.
ℹ Input `..1` is `cf < right.cf`.
```

Comment: What is `cf`?  A vector, a data.frame?

Comment: It is a vector in the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the function below does what the question asks for. It returns a logical vector of values to be `filter`ed.

```
keep_ci <- function(x, mean, sd, conf = 0.99){
  p <- c((1 - conf)/2, 1 - (1 - conf)/2)
  qq <- qnorm(p, mean = mean, sd = sd)
  x > qq[1] & x < qq[2]
}

library(dplyr)

set.seed(2021)
x <- rnorm(1e3, mean = 20)
m <- mean(x)
s <- sd(x)
df1 <- data.frame(x)
df1 %>% filter(keep_ci(x, m, s)) %>% nrow/nrow(df1)
```