# Find 10% highest and lowest values, trim all columns in R

Tags: r, trim

I have a dataset with different columns.
I want to find the 10% highest and lowest values in the RES column and delete all corresponding values.

So far I have this:

```
    library(DescTools)
par(mfcol=c(1,2)); 
Tdata=Trim(data$res, trim=0.1)

Tdata = as.data.frame(Tdata)
hist(data$res); hist(Tdata)
View(cbind(data$res,Tdata))
```

It seems to me that this does the job in deleting the 10% highest and lowest values but it does so by creating a new variable. Instead, I want to delete all corresponding rows from the dataset.

In this [GoogleDrive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18Vu5YCP3b9uoBGKfcelIASF2vGf_KdKx?usp=sharing) folder you can find the dataset.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67795468/8245406) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but

```
library(data.table)
#set to data.table object
dt <- as.data.table(data)

#select only rows between 0.1 and 0.9 quantiles
dt <- dt[res >= quantile(res, 0.1) & res <= quantile(res, 0.9)]
```

Comment: Hello maarvd, just tried and it looks like it works. 
Thank you very much, appreciate :)